# Attaching a Comment to a YAML::Node for Presentation in Output

Tags: c++11, yaml, yaml-cpp

I'm using [yaml-cpp](https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp) with C++11.  I can create a YAML file using something simple like this:

```
#include <yaml-cpp/yaml.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
  YAML::Node  topNode;

  topNode["one"]["two"]["A"] = "foo";
  topNode["one"]["two"]["B"] = 42;

  std::cout << "%YAML 1.2\n---\n" << topNode;
  return 0;
}
```

That will produce a YAML file like this:

```
%YAML 1.2
---
one:
  two:
    A: foo
    B: 42
```

Lovely!

I can also produce **exactly the same** YAML file like this:

```
#include <yaml-cpp/yaml.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
  YAML::Emitter  out;

  out << YAML::BeginMap // document {
      << "one"
        << YAML::BeginMap // one {
        << "two"
          << YAML::BeginMap // two {
          << YAML::Key << "A" << YAML::Value << "foo"
          << YAML::Key << "B" << YAML::Value << 42
          << YAML::EndMap // two }
        << YAML::EndMap // one }
      << YAML::EndMap // document }
      ;

  std::cout << "%YAML 1.2\n---\n"
            << out.c_str();
  return 0;
}
```

The nice thing about the second approach is that I can also add comments into the output file:

```
#include <yaml-cpp/yaml.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
  YAML::Emitter  out;

  out << YAML::BeginMap // document {
      << "one"
        << YAML::BeginMap // one {
        << "two"
          << YAML::BeginMap // two {
          << YAML::Key << "A" << YAML::Value << "foo"
             << YAML::Comment("A should be 'foo'")
          << YAML::Key << "B" << YAML::Value << 42
             << YAML::Comment("B is meaningful")
          << YAML::EndMap // two }
        << YAML::EndMap // one }
      << YAML::EndMap // document }
      ;

  std::cout << "%YAML 1.2\n---\n"
            << out.c_str();
  return 0;
}
```

to produce:

```
%YAML 1.2
---
one:
  two:
    A: foo  # A should be 'foo'
    B: 42  # B is meaningful
```

My question if there is a way to add comments into the first approach? Perhaps something like this:

```
  topNode["one"]["two"]["A"] = "foo";
  topNode["one"]["two"]["A"].addComment("A should be 'foo'");
```

I could subclass `YAML::Node`, adding my `addComment()` method, but I don't want to re-write all of `YAML::Emitter` to get my comment appended appropriately. The code is there, but I don't know how to get to it. How? Can you point me to an example or an approach?

I understand that the YAML specification says that comments are not an integral part of a YAML file, and can be discarded. My users find them useful, so I don't relish a debate that begins with "Your question is stupid."  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible with the current API. The Emitter uses an [EventHandler](https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp/blob/master/include/yaml-cpp/eventhandler.h) which, as you can see, is not able to emit comments.

The [Emit function](https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp/blob/master/src/nodeevents.cpp/#L54) that creates the events does not create any comment events via other means either.

Since `operator<<` on `Node` will internally use the Emitter class, there's no way to emit comments by adding them to a node, unless you rewrite the emitter yourself.